# lua-resty-redis set_keepalive recommended settings

Tags: nginx, redis, lua, openresty

I'm using 
*red:set_keepalive(max_idle_timeout, pool_size)*

(From here: https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#set_keepalive)

with Nginx and trying to determine the best values to use for max_idle_timeout and pool_size.

If my worker_connections is set to 1024, does it make sense to have a pool_size of 1024?

For max_idle_timeout, is 60000 (1 minute) too "aggressive"?  Is it safer to go with a smaller value?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

I think [Check List for Issues](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#check-list-for-issues) section of official documentation has a good guideline for sizing your connection pool:

> Basically if your NGINX handle `n` concurrent requests and your NGINX has `m` workers, then the connection pool size should be configured as `n/m`. For example, if your NGINX *usually* handles 1000 concurrent requests and you have 10 NGINX workers, then the connection pool size should be 100.

So, if you expect 1024 concurrent requests that actually connect to Redis then a good size for your pool is 1024/`worker_processes`. Maybe a few more to account for uneven request distribution among workers.

Your keepalive should be long enough to account for the way traffic arives. If your traffic is constant then you can lower your timeout. Or stay with 60 seconds, in most cases longer timeout won't make any noticeable difference.